# Can't install module using composer

Tags: composer-php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have problem installing the user-management(https://github.com/webvimark/user-management) module with composer. I get following error

```
[UnexpectedValueException]

Could not parse version constraint <=2.*: Invalid version string "2.*"
```

I added

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable" : true,
```

to composer.json. Also I updated composer with

```
composer self-update
```

but still no luck. Then I tried installing other modules but the same error is there.

Note: I already have modules installed on the current project, all were installed without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in composer-asset-plugin which is currently being fixed. See [here](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin/issues/129) for discussion on this issue.

Comment: Looks like that's the problem. I will check and update further

Comment: I had the issue because I included composer-asset-plugin in both my local composer file and globally included it. The solution was to remove it from my local composer.json file, remove it manually from my composer.lock file (it wouldn't work without doing this) and then run `composer update`.

Answer (score 2):

Run below command to fix this bug

```
composer global require "fxp / composer-asset-plugin: 1.0.1"
```

Comment: I ran this command, the error is gone but still can't add any module as it's now giving the error `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. `

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of your vendor's folder and composer.lock, then delete it and run:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0"
composer install
composer update
```

Try to install user-management package again.